# Overriding generic constraint in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Apologies if this would be a better fit for the software engineering stack exchange, but as this is fairly language-specific, I believe I'm asking in the right place.

I have a project which involves converting a sizable codebase from Java to C#. The original Java project has an interface roughly equivalent to the following C# snippet.

```cs
public interface IEntry<out T> where T : class, IEntry<T>{
  T SetName(string nameIn);

  string GetName();
}
```

It also contains a basic implementation of this interface.

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntry<T> : IEntry<T> where T : BaseEntry<T>{
  private string name;
  internal object extraData;

  public T SetName(string nameIn){
    name = nameIn;
    return (T)this;
  }

  public string GetName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

The problem arises in the class which holds entries of types implementing the `IEntry<T>` interface.

```cs
public class ObjectHolder<T> where T : class, IEntry<T>{
  private readonly List<T> entries;
  private readonly bool canGetExtraData;

  public ObjectHolder(){
    //HasGenericBaseType simply checks if the first type implements the second type
    canGetExtraData = HasGenericBaseType(typeof(T), typeof(BaseEntry<>));
  }

  public void Add(T entry){
    entries.Add(entry);
  }

  public void DoSomething(int index){
    if(!canGetExtraData){
      T entry = entries[index];
      object extraData = ((BaseEntry<T>)entry).extraData; <-- This cast fails on compilation
      //Something gets done with the extraData object
    }
  }
}
```

The indicated line gives me the below error on compilation.

```
error CS0314: The type `T' cannot be used as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method `BaseEntry<T>'. There is no boxing or type parameter conversion from `T' to `BaseEntry<T>'
```

I understand why I get this error, but I'm struggling to find a way around it. How could the above class be redesigned to allow access to the internal object field on types extending `BaseEntry<T>`?

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't use class restriction and instead perform it at run-time? (Obviously you've seen plenty of answers which show how to use `(object)` to get around error at casting time... so not closing as duplicate).

Comment: So `BaseEntry<T>` is not equal to `IEntry<T>` You have a mammal that implements `ILegs`. but not everything that has `ILegs` is a mammal. Is there any reason you cant push `extraData` back to interface? Also there is other really suspect stuff going on here, like HasGenericBaseType. unfortunately with this sort of question, a concrete answer is problematic as we have no idea what problems you are trying to solve

Comment: Declare it as `T extraData { get; set; }` on the interface? Incidentally this whole pattern you describe is very similar to [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Comment: IMHO define some other `internal interface IExtraData` with no generic constraint, then you won't need to prove to the compiler that `T : BaseEntry<T>`. That simplifies `canGetExtraData` to `if (entries[index] is IExtraData extra) ... extra.extraData;`

Comment: Because the Java runtime doesn't actually implement generics, it is less strict about forcing constraints on edge cases like this.

Comment: @00110001 yep, HasGenericBaseType was an ugly hack that came out of me attempting to replicate the behavior of Java's isAssignableTo. I think I'm going to opt to make the extra data mandatory and add a method to the interface for it. If you want the SO points, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically `BaseEntry<T>` is not equal to `IEntry<T>`

Analogy :  You have a `Mammal` that implements `ILegs`, but not everything that has `ILegs` is a `Mammal`.

There are few fixes that you might want to look at, either pushing `extraData` back to `IEntry<T>` or as @[JeremyLakeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139809/jeremy-lakeman) suggested, creating a separate generic or / non generic *interface* for `IExtraData` and constrain by that. The answer would depend on whether `IEntry<T>` always has extra data.

Comment: Just implemented this in my project using the extra interface idea, as I realized that some entries did not need the extra data. Thanks for the solid analogy, that really set me on the right track